# Is there a tirck in the get_xxxx function in the general_template.php file?

Tags: get-template-part

I'm a newbie in WordPress and I need a big help to understand how do-action works.

It seems  there is a relationship between the instruction `do_action` and the code that follows it in the get_xxx function that I don't understand. For example, in the following function :

```
function get_header( $name = null ) {

    do_action( 'get_header', $name );

        $templates = array();
        $name = (string) $name;
        if ( '' !== $name ) {
                $templates[] = "header-{$name}.php"; // instruction 1
        }

        $templates[] = 'header.php'; // instruction 2

        locate_template( $templates, true ); 
}
```

There is a `do_action` at the beginning to find `header.php`. Then afterwards, a series of codes are doing the same thing but with likely an issue because the content of the variable `$templates` of the line "instruction 1" is always overridden by the one in the line of "instruction 2" because it is not a "if then else".

In every function get_xxxx we have the same structure. I guess there is a relationship between the `do_action` call and the series of codes that follow but I don't get it.

I will be very grateful if somebody can help me to understand this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `do_action`:

```
do_action( 'get_header', $name );
```

its triggering the action `get_header`, so all actions attached using `add_action` to the action `'get_header'` will be executed, its also passing the `$name` as parameter to the functions by example:

```
function my_function($name){
    echo "The Action sent me the name:".$name."!!";
}

add_action('get_header', 'my_function');
```

when the `do_action( 'get_header', $name );` is executed `my_function` will be called with `$name` as a parameter, this way you can do "something" before the header template is loaded.

`instruction 2` is not overriding  `instruction 1` its adding the default `'header.php'` to the array as a fallback, if you are calling a custom header the `$templates` array will be like this (using `get_header('custom');`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => header-custom.php
    [1] => header.php
)
```

[locate_template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) will try to find and load with `require_once` the first template, if it doesnt exist or it cant find it, it will fallback to `header.php` and try to load that one too.

Comment: So one will effectively use get_header function only when he chooses to write and use header-name.php file instead of header.php provided by default in wordpress. And moreover if he wants something to be done before the template header-name.php  being invoked he can do it in my_function otherwise my_function can be just a return instruction, do I  understand rightly? ("name" stands for "custom" in your wording I guess)

Comment: yes and yes, provided that we use a name when using the function `get_header('custom')` -> `"header-{$name}.php"` -> `header-custom.php`